# Read mat points in YAML in OpenCV

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, file-io, yaml

I am trying to read matrices from a YAML file but it does not show any output.
following is the cpp code.

```
int main()
{
    string filename = "test.yml";
    cout << endl << "Reading: " << endl;
    FileStorage fs;
    fs.open(filename, FileStorage::READ);

    Mat matPts;
    fs["matPts"] >> matPts;                                                                  
    cout << endl
        << "matPts = " << matPts << endl;    
return 0;
```

}

The YAML file look like this

```
%YAML:1.0
version: 3
frame0region0:
   numPts: 2
   matPts: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 2
      cols: 2
      dt: i
      data: [ 528, 93, 563, 128 ]
   attribute: head
frame0region1:
   numPts: 2
   matPts: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 2
      cols: 2
      dt: i
      data: [ 629, 101, 671, 143 ]
   attribute: head
frame0region2:
   numPts: 2
   matPts: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 2
      cols: 2
      dt: i
      data: [ 1114, 368, 1187, 446 ]
   attribute: head
frame0numValidRegions: 3
```

I want to store matrices, frame no and region no and then write it in another xml or text file in a different structure.

Comment: If anyone can help

Comment: Your YML is ill-formed. Do you have control on its creation? Can you show the code?

Comment: No actually it is generated by a tool, I cannot edit the code.